# C Programming outputting bytes into a file

Tags: c, file, char, byte

I am trying to write a compression program, and the logic works fine when I print bits onto screen, however I am also trying to put these bits into a file. I do this by storing them into a char and outputting that char. This method works file for all characters other than things like space (0010 0000)  or tabs (0000 1001). Is there some way of outputting a space or tab into a file?

```
void writeByte(char byte, FILE *comp){  
    fputc(byte,comp);

} //writing byte to file

void writeBit(int bit, FILE *comp){
    if(ind >= 0){
        byte|= (bit<<ind);
        ind--;
    }
    else{
        writeByte(byte,comp); //write byte to file
        reset();
        writeBit(bit,comp);
    }
    //printf("%d\n", bit);

} //storing bits in a byte
```

Comment: What makes you think that simply `fputc`'ing them does *not* work?

Comment: I checked the size of the file. My test file had two spaces, which when compressed should be a dollarsign and space, however only a $ is output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this one out. I needed to add a null character to indicate end of string.